# Push to new view from SearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Trying to push to a new view from the results of a search and for some reason the code isn't being called. Sorry I can't be more descriptive.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self.table deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
int selectedTemplateID = [((CollectionItem*)[cllct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).tID intValue];

ACollection *newView = [[ACollection alloc] initWithID:selectedTemplateID];
newView.template = [cllct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(tableView == self.table) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
    newView.theTitle = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
}
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    NSLog(@"Should push");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
    newView.theTitle = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you set your TableVIewDelegate ?

Comment: check with breake points this method called or not/?

Comment: if your delegate method is invoked, then is your application navigation based or view based?

Comment: I have set my Table Delegate. I believe so anyway. I've used break points and no it's not being called. My application is navigation based I believe.

Comment: try to compare tableview with tag

Comment: then surely you forgot to set Delegate & Datasource for your tableView. and your tableview also not displaying any data, right?

Comment: No my Table is displaying data and the push to new view does work. It just doesn't work from the search display controller which is what I want it do to.

Comment: newView is a viewController or View?

Answer (score -1):

First check the datasource and delegat of tableview.
remove `[self.table deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` and check once.